# How to generate key press events in Qt app to system (win7) (simulate user pressing keys on keyboard)?

Tags: qt, keyboard, keyevent

Question in the title is quite precise.

I need to generate certain key events in my app, so OS can handle them as "normal, user" key presses. How to deal with that in Qt? Is there any neat way to solve this problem?

Comment: For Qt users that lib might be useful: http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate Windows keyboard presses using the Win API function `keybd_event`, e.g.:

```
#include "windows.h"

keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: But you should probably use `SendInput` instead.

Comment: is there a way to do in only using Qt, so that it will be cross-platform